# How to download a file from SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, download, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to download a file from a SharePoint document library using PowerShell, but I am receiving an error that I don't know how to get past.

```
$localFileName1 = "E:\Temp\SOP-Cache\" + $pdfFileName;
$file = $streamSite.GetFile($pdfFileWithoutUrl);
$filebytes = $file.OpenBinary()
$action = [System.IO.FileMode]::Create
$filestream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($localFileName1, $action)
$binarywriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($filestream)
$binarywriter.write($filebytes)
$binarywriter.Close()
```

Error I'm receiving:

> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "write" and the argument count:
>   "1".

I think the reason is because the $binarywriter.write method has multiple overloads, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: first guess: cast type of the argument? `$binarywriter.write([byte[]]$filebytes)`

Comment: No go, same error.  Thanks for the suggestion though, I wasn't sure how to cast in PowerShell.

Comment: on last PS version, even your current code looks fine. What version of PS you have? Can you confirm `$filebytes` is not null? Just to be sure, try also define type of the variable with `[byte[]]$filebytes = $file.OpenBinary()`